# How to get rid from intermediate server and manage direct connection from IP-PBX to the streaming software?

Tags: streaming, sip, flash, rtmp

I found this article:
[www.codeproject.com/Articles/1077937/Possible-ways-to-organize-interaction-between-co](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1077937/Possible-ways-to-organize-interaction-between-co),
and I know that there exist a code for the flash player.
Can I use only code for managing connections (as in the articles examples) and free flash player code and therefore get rid from integration software?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific but in reality the idea of the integration software is the following:

- Session management
- Multi-codec/format support
- Interface Resource
- Scheduling

Normally IP PBX supports SIP only, hence you need the transcoding between the SIP world (Audio + Video) and the Webcast world (Web browser/client/camera). Integration software as the one defined do a pretty good job and some of them are open Source (Wooza), If you want to  replace them, I would do it with an MCU which support RMTP/Flash. Take a look at McuWeb project. Otherwise you need to write SIP Client code as well to integrate it with the SIP world